# Why is this a dependent clause?

Tags: syntax

The sentence is:

> The thieves stole some of Beauval Zoo’s most valued members—seven golden lion tamarins and ten silvery marmosets.

On khan academy they said that "seven golden lion tamarins and ten silvery marmosets" is an dependent clause. However, from what I read, a dependent clause requires verbs which this doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: The academy is wrong. _Seven golden lion tamarins and ten silvery marmosets_ is not a clause but a noun phrase. It's called a supplementary **appositive** and it refers to the preceding noun phrase _some of Beauval Zoo’s most valued members_. It's said to be in apposition because if it is substituted for the preceding noun phrase it yields an entailment of the original: _The thieves stole seven golden lion tamarins and ten silvery marmosets_.

Answer (score 1):

Reference

http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm
http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm

> The thieves stole some of Beauval Zoo’s most valued members — seven golden lion tamarins and ten silvery marmosets.

The "seven golden..." part is definitely not a dependent clause (subordinate clause).  The "seven golden..." part of the sentence renames the noun "most valued members" and so is a noun phrase or an appositive.

If the sentence read "After the thieves stole..." then that first part of the sentence would be a dependent clause.